# Nokia Widget: How can I pass a startup parameter?

Tags: widget, nokia

We are developing a new UI for one of the products and we are exploring using the Nokia Widgets, It seems to do almost everything we need, but we need to pass an initial token to the widget on startup.

So far I have not found any way to do so (looking on the Nokia forums, and Google) so I am wondering if it is possible at all.

I'd like my app to start the widget with a single parameter, that's all I need.

Comment: What is "Nokia Widget"? Is that Web Runtime widgets? Or rather Widsets?

Comment: "Nokia Widget" = WRT Widgets on S60 3.2 / 5.0 platforms.